# How to get pydev code completion using super

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, super, code-completion

Is there a way to configure PyDev or hint for code completion when using super()?

For example:

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self,):
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

In this case I don't have access to `class A`'s source code but need to know what parameters to provide in the init call which will also tell me what parameters to require in B. I haven't seen anything about super in the type hinting documentation. I also prefer not to directly use `A.__init__()` if possible because I believe I remember reading that `super()` is the correct way to do it.

Comment: When you call `__init__()` it should throw an error like `"n positional arguments missing"`. That will show you what `A` needs. Or look at the documentation if it's in a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humm, that sounds like a shortcoming in the PyDev type inference engine. Please report that at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev (the type inference is one of the current development focuses).

Comment: Wasn't sure if I was missing a keyword for type hinting or something. Thanks!